# How to turn off Cursor Blinking in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, cursor

I have a small netbook and the `writing cursor` pretty much disappears when i move it around with the arrows in docs. I switched from Ubuntu where I had the Cursor Blinking off in Universal Access. That use to solve the problem.

Comment: What release of Lubuntu?   An old one using LXDE or a modern one with LXQt?

Comment: Have you tried changing the cursor to a different one, in my play just now I've found some have very thin text cursors, whilst others have much thicker (and easier to spot).  Refer https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.2/appearance.html?highlight=cursor

Comment: I have lubuntu 18.04 with LXDE

Answer (score 1):

There's a short answer and a long answer to this.

## Short answer

#### Lubuntu 18.04/LXDE

Sorry, there is no easily accessible option.

However, there is a hidden feature in LXSession that can help. You can change the config like so:

**`~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf`**

```
[GTK]
iNet/CursorBlink=no
```

and log out and log back in again to make the change.

#### Lubuntu >18.04/LXQt

`lxqt-config-input` offers an option to adjust the blink rate. To set it to non-blinking:

1. Navigate to Menu » Preferences » LXQt Settings » Keyboard and Mouse » Keyboard.
2. Set the Cursor flash time to 0ms.
3. Click Apply.
4. Click Close.

The [Lubuntu Manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/3/3.2/3.2.8/keyboard_and_mouse.html) covers `lxqt-config-input` in greater detail.

## Long answer

Technically, both solutions are only changing the settings for the underlying toolkit— GTK and Qt, respectively. In ≤18.04/LXDE, Lubuntu used mostly GTK apps, while after it was mostly Qt apps. That doesn't mean you couldn't install Qt apps in the mainly GTK system and vice versa. The changes above would not affect those "foreign" apps. The more general solution for the two respective toolkits follows.

#### GTK

Change the config for both current GTK versions:

**`~/.config/gtk-2.0/settings.ini`** and **`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`**

```
[Settings]
gtk-cursor-blink = false
```

#### Qt

This should be a simple matter of changing the Qt config with the likes of the following:

**`~/.qt/qtrc`**

```
[General]
cursorFlashTime=0
```

**`~/.config/Trolltech.conf`** and **`~/.config/QtProject.conf`**

```
[Qt]
cursorFlashTime=0
```

or through the `qtconfig` application (see the `qt-qt4config` package in 18.04) via Interface » Cursor Flash Time » No Blinking but I could not get this to work in 18.04.

There is a [page](http://www.jurta.org/en/prog/noblink) that covers this topic more generally for a variety of different applications, toolkits, and desktop environments that would be good to consult for any edge cases.